# How can I play sound using Python's included batteries (on linux)?

Tags: python, linux, audio, alsa

I'm running Arch Linux with Python 3.5.1

I would *expect* that using the [ossaudiodev](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ossaudiodev.html) module, I should be able to do something like this:

```
import ossaudiodev

beep = b'Fri Jan 13 08:37:01 CST 2012' * 42  # Hey, it works with `aplay` as a text file
snd = ossaudiodev.open('w')
snd.write(beep)
```

And then I'd hear a beep sound. I know the data works with `aplay` if it's just contents in a text file. However, when I run the above, I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/dsp'
```

Which is true, I don't have a `/dev/dsp`. So how do I play me a sound?

(note, if I install the `alsa-oss` package for backwards compatibility and do

```
# modprobe snd-pcm-oss
```

That produces `/dev/dsp` and `/dev/audio`, either of which I can use to play sounds [though I did notice that I have to do `snd.flush()` if I'm running an interactive interpreter].

I don't want to do this because this is old style and also appears to be blocking. I know my current sound setup has a way to run more than one sound at a time, because I can listen to music through my browser and still run `aplay`, so I know it's doing something else. I just can't find the right documentation for that)

Comment: The `audiodev` package was removed in Python 3 because it works only on Suns and SGIs. The PortAudio bindings (`PyAudio`) are not included.